# Pressing Tab or ArrowKeys using Chrome debugging protocol, real context

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Hey I'm trying to use the [remote debugging protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to insert text in an input box then press TAB twice to set focus in the other input box (utilizing tabindex focus ability).

I've tried the input domain. both type:"char" and keydown+keyup.

```js
Input.dispatchKeyEvent({                                                  
   modifiers: 0,                                                                                                  
   nativeVirtualKeyCode: 9,                                                                                       
   text: "\t",                                                                                                    
   type: "char",                                                                                                  
   unmodifiedText: "\t",                                                                                          
   windowsVirtualKeyCode: 9                                                                                       
}
```

inside a textarea for example it seems to simply add a indent to the text itself rather than just skip to the next focus-able elment.

Also any other "System OS level" keypressing is something I can't figure out how to do (such as arrowkeys, pageup/down etc)

P.S:
I don't want

```
elem.value = 'text'
```

solutions, cause I aim to simulate real user clicks or key pressing.

any idea of how to use debugging protocol in such a way?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, I was missing "key" property